# Multiple order by with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table that organizes the shows of a program (every program will be performed in multiple shows). I need to have a view where they are ordered into programs but chronologically.

The SQL Query is much longer in real but in short this:

```
SELECT * FROM show_table ORDER BY program, timebegin
```

results in this table:

```
    # show_table

program  |   timebegin     
3399        Do, 01. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
3399        Fr, 02. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
3399        Sa, 03. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
3401        Do, 08. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
3401        Fr, 09. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
3401        Sa, 10. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
3719        So, 04. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
3739        Mo, 12. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
3777        So, 04. Nov. 2012 12 Uhr
```

Hence, the programs are itself ordered by time, but I want to have the order slightly different, like that:

```
program  |   timebegin     
3399        Do, 01. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
3399        Fr, 02. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
3399        Sa, 03. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
3777        So, 04. Nov. 2012 12 Uhr
3719        So, 04. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
3401        Do, 08. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
3401        Fr, 09. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
3401        Sa, 10. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr       
3739        Mo, 12. Nov. 2012 20 Uhr
```

Now everything is ordered by `timebegin`, while programs are not intercepted. Basically, I do not want to sort by program, but by `timebegin`, but group all programs together.

Is this possible with pure mySQL or do I have to apply server side logic?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just `ORDER BY timebegin`?  That appears to be how your second example is actually ordered.  Or is it just coincidence that it turned out that way?

Comment: In other words, if `ORDER BY timebegin` doesn't work for you in general, please edit your example to show one or more cases where it works incorrectly and what the correct output should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT show_table.program, show_table.timebegin
FROM show_table
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT program, MIN(timebegin) AS firsttime
    FROM show_table
    GROUP BY program
) AS groups
ON (show_table.program = groups.program)
ORDER BY groups.firsttime, show_table.program, show_table.timebegin;
```

Basically, there's another query that gets the minimum `timebegin` (called `firsttime`) for each program group, then the query is joined to the original table. Then we just order by `firsttime` to get the program groups ordered correctly and by `timebegin` to get the rows inside a program group ordered correctly. The `program` field in `ORDER BY` between them is in there in case two program groups happen to have the same `firsttime`, so we don't mix them in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Watching your desired result, I think you could use

```
SELECT * FROM show_table 
ORDER BY timebegin, program
```

If you want all programs for every timebegin, try this

```
SELECT timebegin, GROUP_CONCAT(program)
FROM show_table 
GROUP BY timebegin
ORDER BY timebegin
```

Take a look at [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) man page.

Comment: `ORDER BY timebegin, program` orders everything by timebegin and does only order those shows that have the same timebegin by program.

GROUP_CONCAT does not work in my case, as I want these three steps:

1. Order all shows by program.
2. Order inside these program packages by timebegin
3. Order all of these program packages by timebegin

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `ORDER BY timeBegin, program`? It's much easier when `timeBegin`'s data type is `DateTime`. Right?

Comment: timeBegin is actually a timestamp, I changed these for reading purposes.

Comment: @shredding great, have you tried changing the columns in the order by? :)

Comment: Yes, please see my comment above by marco.

Comment: @shredding you mentioned `group the program together`. how does your result look like?

Comment: I did not mean group in terms of mySQLs `GROUP BY`. I want to have the programs as inseparable packages and these packages grouped by time.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I do not want to sort by program, but by timebegin, but group all programs together.

These requirements are at odds with each other. You'll have to choose which column is more important.  While ordering by `timebegin` first, the only way that programs will stay grouped together is if the data happens to be in that order, as in, you don't have any instance of program 2 happening in between two instances of another program.  This is somewhat doubtful.